# Editing a Flask API

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, flask-admin

I am trying to implement some changes into a deployed Flask API.

Am I able to edit files in the deployed API and have the changes take effect without having the restart the API build?

Comment: Usually, no. For changes to take effect in a typical production deployment, you usually have to restart the webserver service or WSGI server (depending on the deploymnet methods). Files should only get automatically reloaded in a development environment when the DEBUG flag is set to true.

Comment: Tho if your environment uses an API gateway you can deploy on another server instance and switch your REST endpoints for 0 downtime.

Comment: Do you know how the WSGI server can be restarted in order to reflect recent changes?

Comment: Thank you @sytech

Answer (score 0):

You can have the changes take effect by issuing:

```
touch /path/to/scriptalias.wsgi
```

It should be the file specified in:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/flaskapp.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Webserver restart is necessary for changes to take effect.
After changes issues below command. The lag will be only in seconds.

sudo service apache2 restart

Ps. - Need root user permission for this.